# OPENGL ES not working : no Current context

Tags: android, opengl-es, egl

I tried the program as shown in book OpenGL ES2 for Android, but it's not working!!

I have tested in Odroid E, samsung s3, samsung y, samsung star!!

```
the gl version suported returns 2, but i get
11-22 15:09:45.804: E/oGl-es v(9047): 2.0:131072
11-22 15:09:45.804: E/libEGL(9047): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context     (logged once per thread)
11-22 15:09:45.804: E/unable to(9047): createShader
11-22 15:09:45.804: E/libEGL(9047): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
11-22 15:09:45.804: E/unable to(9047): createShader
11-22 15:09:45.804: E/libEGL(9047): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
11-22 15:09:45.804: E/Error creating(9047): GL programObject
11-22 15:09:45.812: E/render(9047): set
11-22 15:09:46.062: E/Results of validating program:(9047): 0
11-22 15:09:46.062: E/Results of validating program:(9047): Log:
```

Below are my code

```
public class Main_OGLT1 extends Activity {

    MySurface mGLSurfaceView;
private boolean renderSet;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mGLSurfaceView = new MySurface(this);//(this); //instantiation

        ActivityManager actMan = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        ConfigurationInfo mConfigInfo = actMan.getDeviceConfigurationInfo();
        boolean isES2Compat = (mConfigInfo.reqGlEsVersion >= 0x20000);
        Log.e("oGl-es v",mConfigInfo.getGlEsVersion()+":"+ mConfigInfo.reqGlEsVersion);
        if(isES2Compat){


            renderSet = true;
            Log.e("render","set");

        }


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main__oglt1, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        // The activity must call the GL surface view's onResume() on activity onResume().
        super.onResume();
        mGLSurfaceView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        // The activity must call the GL surface view's onPause() on activity onPause().
        super.onPause();
        mGLSurfaceView.onPause();
    }

}
```

The class MySurface :

```
    public class MySurface extends GLSurfaceView{

    public MySurface(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        setRenderer(new MyTestRenderer(getContext()));
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is with glSurfaceView, as it does not run on the OpenGL thread. The glSurfaceView should be on the main android thread.

Here you find additional info about it:

[opengl es api with no current context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286819/opengl-es-api-with-no-current-context)

[OpenGL ES 2.0 Context in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807857/opengl-es-2-0-context-in-android)

Hope this help.

Comment: Actually, if i comment setEGLContextClientVersion(2); i get unimplemented gl call log

Comment: The link you posted doesnot correspond to my question, as i dnt initiate anything before calling setRenderer. Also, my device definitely supports openGL ES2

Comment: This helped. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399087/glcreateshader-and-glcreateprogram-fail-on-android   but now compiling shader fails stating no main function for shader. but the shader string have void main()

Comment: @nmxprime *"Actually, if i comment setEGLContextClientVersion(2); i get unimplemented gl call log"* I'm not sure why you would do that to begin with. You can't make 2.0 calls without specifying it as the client version.

Comment: @b1nary.atr0phy, That's a blunter i did while i hadn't know what tat would have mean to be