# Call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread) Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, opengl-es

I am working on a phonegap, jquerymobile HTML5 app.

I am getting the following error: "Call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)"
I found solutions on similar problems but nothing worked for me.

I don't understand why this error occure, but as I observed this error occur when I call a new page on html.
My html code it is similar with the code in this example: 
http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_pages

I am using eclipse along with Android SDK Emulator.

My Activity class is mentioned in start guides of Phonegap Android. This is my Activity class:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: does it affect anything ? I dont know about solution but i also keep on getting it at times but it never harmed !

Comment: At this moment, it's not affecting anything. But I don't know if it will affect something later.

Comment: ok so thing is this error is not specific to `cordova`(i have no idea what it is).. A simple google search will tell you that many people are having same issue in android.. you might want to check those posts out.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal Whether it *appears* to be affecting something or not is irrelevant. Warnings/errors aren't thrown for no reason. Just because you don't think it's harming something, doesn't mean it isn't or won't.

Comment: @b1nary.atr0phy ya i understand it completely.. i was just trying to say that its a common issue !

Comment: See will this help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20159821/opengl-es-not-working-no-current-context

Answer (score 0):

You can write so:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>
```